# Creating a DatabaseProxy for a ServerlessCluster in CDK?

Tags: amazon-rds, aws-cdk, aws-cdk-typescript

**Background**

Using the AWS Console, one can create an Aurora Postgres Serverless database cluster and, in the same action, create an RDS Proxy for said cluster.

I'm trying to do ^ that ^ via CDK, but I can't see a way to do it via the [CDK documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_rds.ServerlessCluster.html).

**Problem**

I can create a `ServerlessCluster`, but its interface type is `IServerlessCluster` ... unfortunately, the `DatabaseProxy` construct requires a `proxyTarget` property with an interface type of `IDatabaseCluster` -- since `IServerlessCluster` !== `IDatabaseCluster`, the constructor complains.

**Question**

So how is one supposed to use CDK to create a DatabaseProxy for a ServerlessCluster?  The [DatabaseProxy documentation's example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_rds.DatabaseProxy.html) doesn't work because of the noted mismatch.

**Existing Code**

```
import { 
    AuroraPostgresEngineVersion,
    AuroraCapacityUnit,
    DatabaseClusterEngine,
    DatabaseProxy,
    IDatabaseCluster,
    ProxyTarget,
    ServerlessCluster
} from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-rds';
import { Duration, RemovalPolicy } from 'aws-cdk-lib';
import { IVpc, ISecurityGroup, SubnetType } from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-ec2';
import { Construct } from 'constructs';
import { Stage } from '../../bin/bin';

interface Props {
    scope: Construct;
    stage: Stage;
    name: string;
    vpc: IVpc;
    sgs: ISecurityGroup[];
    engineVersion?: AuroraPostgresEngineVersion;
}

export const createAuroraPostgresRdsServerlessClusterWithProxy = ({
    scope,
    stage,
    name,
    vpc,
    sgs,
    engineVersion
  }: Props) => {

    const dbCluster = new ServerlessCluster(scope, name, {
        engine: DatabaseClusterEngine.auroraPostgres({
          version: engineVersion ?? Object.values(AuroraPostgresEngineVersion).slice(-1)[0]
        }),
        vpc,
        securityGroups: sgs,
        removalPolicy: RemovalPolicy.DESTROY,
        defaultDatabaseName: 'myDatabaseName',
        clusterIdentifier: `myClusterId`,
        scaling: { 
            autoPause: Duration.minutes(5),
            minCapacity: stage === 'dev' ? AuroraCapacityUnit.ACU_2 : AuroraCapacityUnit.ACU_8,
            maxCapacity: stage === 'dev' ? AuroraCapacityUnit.ACU_16 : AuroraCapacityUnit.ACU_64,
        },
        vpcSubnets: {
            subnetType: stage === 'dev' ? SubnetType.PUBLIC : SubnetType.PRIVATE_ISOLATED
        },
    });

    // -- do something to add dbCluster to a proxy ... this doesn't work:
    const proxy = new DatabaseProxy(scope, 'Proxy', {
        proxyTarget: ProxyTarget.fromCluster(dbCluster),
        secrets: [dbCluster.secret!],
        vpc,
    });
    
}
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with the specifics, but three generic approaches are: (a) Craft the L1 constructs [by hand](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/rds-proxy-cfn.html); (b) Start with a L2 construct and override select properties (see this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/20197) for Serverless V2); (c) Pad out required but missing methods to satisfy `IDatabaseCluster`.  Options b and c may not work, it depends on the domain. The [CDK source](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/blob/main/packages/%40aws-cdk/aws-rds/lib/proxy.ts) is a good place start.

Comment: Hey @Dan were you able to accomplish this? :')